# Code optimization - multiple events

Tags: jquery

I'm just wondering if there is a best case to write this code:

```
  $('#set_duration_30').click(function(event) {
    $('#duration').val(30);
  });

  $('#set_duration_60').click(function(event) {
    $('#duration').val(60);
  });

  $('#set_duration_90').click(function(event) {
    $('#duration').val(90);
  });

  $('#set_duration_120').click(function(event) {
    $('#duration').val(120);
  });
```

Comment: Are you optimizing for performance, code readability, code size, ...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give your elements a css-class, for example `durationsetter`. Also give them an attribute that contains their value, for example `data-duration`.

i.e.

```
<input type="button" class="durationsetter" data-duration="30" />
```

Then your jQuery will look like this:

```
$('.durationsetter').click(function(e) {
    $('#duration').val($(this).attr('data-duration'));
});
```